# Can I use classic PS2 gamepads on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps2

I have the classic PS2-Controllers. Can I use them (obviously not per se) on the PS3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use them ... obviously you need an adapter.
There are several 3rd party adapters on the web.
This is one of them: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Playstation-PS3-Controller-Adapter-rumble/dp/B001WH620M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=videogames&qid=1278532604&sr=8-1

Comment: I built an arcade stick using a PS2 gamepad and I use in my PS3 (and PC) with a generic adapter. I've tested with fighting games like SF4 (all), Marvel vs. Capcom 3 and Blaz Blue.